# DotNetRDF QueryBuilder Filter using LangMatches

Tags: c#, .net, sparql, rdf, dotnetrdf

After googling for about an hour now, I am not be able to find anything that help me to put a filter using dotNetRDF query builder to construct a SPARQL query. Following is my code so far:

```
var queryBuilder = VDS.RDF.Query.Builder.QueryBuilder
.Select(keys.ToArray())
.Where(a =>
    a.Subject(string.Format("<{0}>", uri)).PredicateUri("gwsw:hasAspect").Object("aspect")
        .Subject("aspect").PredicateUri("rdf:type").Object("type")
        .Subject("type").PredicateUri("rdfs:label").Object("label")
)
.Optional(opt => opt
    .Where(a =>
        a.Subject("aspect").PredicateUri("sn:hasValue").Object("value")
            .Subject("type").PredicateUri("sn:hasUnit").Object("unit")
        )
)
.Filter(fil => 
    fil.LangMatches() //What to do here
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `.Filter((builder) => builder.LangMatches(builder.Lang(builder.Variable("label")), "en");`

Comment: @AKSW, this looks like the answer...

Comment: @StanislavKralin To be honest, I don't really know whether this is correct or even does compile. I never used dotNetRDF nor did I implement anything in C#. I just went shortly through the documentation which contains a `Filter` example for `regex` + I checked the API docs for `LangMatches`

Comment: @AKSW, Thanks a ton. this was exactly I was looking for. Can you also guide how to put OR condition if LANG is empty for label? Request you to post your comment as answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured that out `filter.IsBlank(filter.Lang(filter.Variable("label"))) || filter.LangMatches(filter.Lang(filter.Variable("label")), "en"))`